# How to run a different query depending on case switch statement? (C#)

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Here's my code which works up to a point:

```
var Data = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();

int caseSwitch = 0;

if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    caseSwitch = 1;
}
else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    caseSwitch = 2;
}
else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
{
    caseSwitch = 3;
}

 var query = from x in Data
             let sw = caseSwitch
             select
                 sw == 1 ? new { Name = x[6], Age = x[2], Date = x[4], Score = x[7]  }
                 : sw == 2 ? new { Name = x[9], Age = x[1], Date = x[0], Score = x[3] }
                 : sw == 3 ? new { Name = x[5], Age = x[8], Date = x[2], Score = x[1] }
                 : null;
```

It seems the code stops working when I have up to 8 case switch scenarios...the error I seem to get once I have 8 scenarios is "Index was outside the bounds of the array" whilst the ": null;" statement is highlighted in yellow.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Index was outside the bounds of the array" would indicate that you have a bad index value for `x` in one (or more) of your cases - the number of switch statements would not cause that error.

Post the line in your select that causes the error.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a limit on the number of switch scenarios that I can include in my query?

Comment: No - the only restriction is that each must return the same anonymous type (same properties in the same order)

Comment: Yipes, it didn't occur to me that the data (x) might be bad (it was good & clean up until now).  Bad data was causing my problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this might be to have the query do everything but the select itself. You can then do your switch like this:

```
IQueryable<whatever> newQuery;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
 case 1: newQuery = query.Select(i => new { Name = i[9], ... }); break;
 case 2: newQuery = query.Select(i => new { Name = i[6], ... }); break;
}
```

Note that you can't use an anonymous type, but that shouldn't be a problem here. This way, you only send the query you actually want, rather than doing a case on the server.

Comment: You _can_ use an anonymous type provided the properties are the same - the compiler will treat them all as the same type.

Comment: Yes, but since you can't use *var* in the newQuery declaration, you have no way of declaring the variable without a specific type.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a conditional statement there at all - since the structure of your query does not change, all you need is a table providing the indexes for `Name`, `Age`, `Date`, and `Score` columns:

```
class ColumnIndex {
    int NameIndex {get;set;}
    int AgeIndex {get;set;}
    int DateIndex {get;set;}
    int ScoreIndex {get;set;}
}
private static readonly ColumnIndex[] ColIndex = new[] {
    new ColumnIndex  {NameIndex = 6, AgeIndex = 2, DateIndex = 4, ScoreIndex = 7}
,   new ColumnIndex  {NameIndex = 9, AgeIndex = 1, DateIndex = 0, ScoreIndex = 3}
,   new ColumnIndex  {NameIndex = 5, AgeIndex = 8, DateIndex = 2, ScoreIndex = 1}
,   ...
};
...
int caseSwitch = -1;

if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    caseSwitch = 0;
}
else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    caseSwitch = 1;
}
else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
{
    caseSwitch = 2;
}
var query = from x in Data
    select new {
        Name  = x[ColIndex[caseSwitch].NameIndex]
    ,   Age   = x[ColIndex[caseSwitch].AgeIndex]
    ,   Date  = x[ColIndex[caseSwitch].DateIndex]
    ,   Score = x[ColIndex[caseSwitch].ScoreIndex]
    };
```